# How to enable CORS in SignalR only for a certain domain?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, signalr

What I want to do is to allow connections from my example.com to signalr.example.com .

This works, but allows for all:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

I found this suggestion:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://example.com")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
        .AllowCredentials();
});
```

But apparently it is for ASP.NET Core, my `app.UseCors()` accepts only a parameter of type `CorsOptions`.

How to enable CORS for a specific address and not all? Thanks.

Comment: OK, [here is how to do it](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/SignalR-2.x-demo/blob/master/SignalR2x/SelfHost/Startup.cs) (for me to search deeper later!)

Comment: i guess you have set your Domain to `example.com` and schema to `https`, whats pain?